# TypeScript not picking overloads

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScript, so I'm thinking I am either doing something wrong or something in my setup is wrong.

My Code:

```
import Animated, { Value } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { useRef } from "react";

const useLazyRef = <T>(initializer: () => T) => {
  const ref = useRef<T>();
  if (ref.current === undefined) {
    ref.current = initializer();
  }
  return ref.current;
};

declare type Atomic = string | number | boolean;
type UseValues = {
  <V extends Atomic>(v: V): [Animated.Value<V>];
  <V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic>(v1: V1, v2: V2): [
    Animated.Value<V1>,
    Animated.Value<V2>
  ];
  <V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic, V3 extends Atomic>(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3
  ): [Animated.Value<V1>, Animated.Value<V2>, Animated.Value<V3>];
  <V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic, V3 extends Atomic, V4 extends Atomic>(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3,
    v4: V4
  ): [
    Animated.Value<V1>,
    Animated.Value<V2>,
    Animated.Value<V3>,
    Animated.Value<V4>
  ];
  <
    V1 extends Atomic,
    V2 extends Atomic,
    V3 extends Atomic,
    V4 extends Atomic,
    V5 extends Atomic
  >(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3,
    v4: V4,
    v5: V5
  ): [
    Animated.Value<V1>,
    Animated.Value<V2>,
    Animated.Value<V3>,
    Animated.Value<V4>,
    Animated.Value<V5>
  ];
  <V extends Atomic>(...values: V[]): Animated.Value<V>[];
};

export const useValues = ((<V extends Atomic>(...values: [V, ...V[]]) =>
  useLazyRef(() => values.map((v) => new Value(v)))) as unknown) as UseValues;

const Yup = () => {
  const [one, two, three] = useValues([0, 0, 0]);
  return [one, two, three];
};

export default Yup;
```

It's long but basic. There are a few overloads but `const [one, two, three] = useValues([0, 0, 0]);` should be using the third overload:

```
<V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic, V3 extends Atomic>(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3
  ): [Animated.Value<V1>, Animated.Value<V2>, Animated.Value<V3>];
```

I'm getting two warnings:

1. `const [one, two, three]` shows 'Tuple type '[AnimatedValue]' of length '1' has no element at index '2'. ts(2493)` - This is already strange. It is referring to the second overload which is a tuple and ignores the third overload?
2. useValues([0, 0, 0]) gives the warning `Overload 2 of 6, '(...values: Atomic[]): AnimatedValue<Atomic>[]', gave the following error. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2769)` - again it refers to the second overload

So I played with this a little to debug. My new code:

```
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

declare type Atomic = string | number | boolean;
declare type UseValues = {
  <V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic, V3 extends Atomic>(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3
  ): [Animated.Value<V1>, Animated.Value<V2>, Animated.Value<V3>];
};
export declare const useValues: UseValues;

const Yup = () => {
  const [one, two, three] = useValues([0, 0, 0]);
  return [one, two, three];
};

export default Yup;
```

Now I'm getting a warning for useValues([0, 0, 0]):

```
const useValues: <Atomic, Atomic, Atomic>(v1: Atomic, v2: Atomic, v3: Atomic) => [Animated.Value<Atomic>, Animated.Value<Atomic>, Animated.Value<...>]
Expected 3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
testing.ts(7, 5): An argument for 'v2' was not provided.
```

I'm clearly passing an array (as should be expected) with three numbers.

## UPDATE

I updated my code to reflect how the assignment actually happens. Sorry about the confusion. This is new to me as well.

Comment: you pass an array when multiple value is needed

Comment: @Austaras, I think you mean I pass `const [one, two, three]` instead of passing multiple values? Could you please give me an example of how I can assign the values in `useValues([0, 0, 0])` to `one`, `two`, and `three`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes me think that `useValues` is a function that return an array. And you are destructuring assignment to the vars one, two, three.

```
  const [one, two, three] = useValues([0, 0, 0]);
```

I am also currious to what will happen if you call useValues with 3 args, e.g.       `const [one, two, three] = useValues(0, 0, 0);`

I am not familiar with this syntax for declaring a type. At first glance, looks like `type UseValues` is an object.

```
declare type UseValues = {
  <V1 extends Atomic, V2 extends Atomic, V3 extends Atomic>(
    v1: V1,
    v2: V2,
    v3: V3
  ): [Animated.Value<V1>, Animated.Value<V2>, Animated.Value<V3>];
};
```

Where does assignment to `useValues` happen?

Sorry for the non-answer answer. Upvoted to see if I can learn something too.

Comment: You are right. It was missing in my code above. Updated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: useValues(0, 0, 0) works. It assigns the values correctly. I think I see what's going on. `export const useValues = ((<V extends Atomic>(...values: [V, ...V[]]) =>
  useLazyRef(() => values.map((v) => new Value(v)))) as unknown) as UseValues;` This iterates over the values in `values.map((v)`. Since v is a comma separated list of values it turns it into an array and assigns to `[one, two, three]`. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: yes, your explanation is what I think is happening too. Took me a minute to read through that nested assignment. TLDR: correct.